# Fragment instanceof in onItemClick

Tags: android, fragment

Im using array adapter for my fragments and on item click action should start that fragment

```
Fragment f = (Fragment) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
if (f instanceof MyFragment) {
    newContent = new MyFragment();
}
```

if clause is always false and i dont know why

there is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this,

```
Object f = Class.forName(ApplicationSession.getInstance().getAppPackage() + "." +parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).newInstance();

if (f instanceof MyFragment) {
    newContent = new MyFragment();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You make a cast from Objet to `Fragment`, so f becomes an instance of `Fragment`... keerthana gives you a solution that will ALWAYS gives you a `MyFragment` instance.

Try to don't make any cast at all.

```
Object f = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
if (f instanceof MyFragment) {
    newContent = new MyFragment();
}
```